# Password Generator in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found this [batch file password generator](https://superuser.com/a/571136/639112):

```
rem 16 stings pwd

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

set pwd=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, 16) DO (
SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768 + 1
for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set pwd=!pwd!%%c
)

echo pwd=%pwd%
```

which I put into a batch file: rand.bat
However when I call rand.bat from another batch file, the environment variable pwd is no longer available.  How do I get it to persist into the calling batch file?

Comment: Note that Cmd's %RANDOM% is a [very poor RNG](http://web.archive.org/web/20190216195619if_/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100617-00/?p=13673).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exiting the called batch implies an `Endlocal` which discards all created local variables.

To overcome this include an `Endlocal` command and **on the same line** repeat the set command.

Due to the [complex inner working of cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts) (which often requires DelayedExpansion) this line is in both scopes and can thus re-create the content of the variable.

```
rem 16 stings pwd

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set alfanum=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789

set pwd=
FOR /L %%b IN (0, 1, 16) DO (
    SET /A rnd_num=!RANDOM! * 62 / 32768 + 1
    for /F %%c in ('echo %%alfanum:~!rnd_num!^,1%%') do set "pwd=!pwd!%%c"
)

echo pwd=%pwd%
Endlocal & set "pwd=%pwd%" & goto :Eof
```